# UIButton UIControl target action 2 actions for single button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontrol

I have a button that has a selected and non-selected state.

My target action code for the button is this:

```
NSArray *targets = [myButton actionsForTarget:self forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if ([targets count] == 0) {
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(save:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When the button is pressed, it goes to selected state in the method.

If the button is selected, a different action should be called. Is there any unintended consequence to doing it this way or is there a way to add actions with UIControlState instead?

```
if (myButton.selected == NO){
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(save:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else{
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(delete:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: It looks OK, nothing bad about the implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
btn.selected = !btn.selected;
if(btn.selected)
{
    //Do whatever you want when button is selected
    [self delete];
}
 else
{
    //Do whatever you want when button isDeselected
     [self save];
}
}
```

Comment: what does the btn.selected = !btn.selected do?

Comment: btn.selected = !btn.selected toggle state of button selected and Deselected!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach might be confusing. You can use like this.

```
 [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   - (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
   {
      if(sender.selected)
         [self save]; 
      else
         [self delete];
   }
   -(void)save
   {
   // your code
   }
   -(void)delete
   {
   // your code
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you are wanting something like toggle button. if i am right use `yourbutton.currentTitle` to follow the functionality. i.e. if `[youtbutton.currentTitle isEqualToString: @"save]"` then you should perform save and set that to delete and vice verse